# How to get the full size picture of graph that plotted in R

Tags: r, plot

I have plotted a histogram graph but it show that the graph has been cut a part like the image show. Is there any solution to solve it?[image]

```
#install.packages("RegressionFactory")
#install.packages("MASS")
#install.packages("qpcR")
#install.packages("olsrr")
#install.packages("car")
#install.packages("ggplot2")


library(RegressionFactory)
library(MASS)
library(qpcR)
library(olsrr)
library(car)
library(openxlsx)
library(ggplot2)

dataset=read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
attach(dataset)
View(dataset)
hist(dataset$CGPA,
     freq = FALSE,
     main = "Chance of admit vs CGPA",
     xlab = "CGPA",
     ylab = "Chance of admit",
     las = 1,
     col = c("skyblue")
)
lines(density(dataset$CGPA), lwd = 4, col = "red")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide appropriate limits to the y-axis

```
set.seed(53)
dat = rnorm(500)

d = density(dat)

hist(dat, ylim = c(0, max(d$y)), freq = FALSE)
lines(d)
```

Comment: While not always a problem, you might want to set `ylim=c(0, max(d$y, hist(dat,plot=F)$density)`. (I'm not certain that the histogram would ever have a density above `density(dat)$y`, so perhaps this is unnecessary.)

Comment: Looking at it more, though ...  `range` will not necessarily be starting at zero, so it's going to shift the y-axis. I suggest changing it to `ylim=c(0, max(d$y))`.

Comment: @r2evans it show me an error that object 'd' not found

Comment: @d.b it solved thanks very much btw can I set my x-axis start from 0?